# (p,q) and (q,p) torus knots are isomorphic

Tags: knot-theory

Can anyone help me understand why these 2 torus knots are isomorphic ?
i tried to prove it using the parametric equations of a torus knot, but it didnt help.

Comment: Imagine putting your knot on a torus, then puncturing the torus somewhere not on the knot.  Then you can squish the knot along with the torus into a band-sum of two annuli.  From here you can just undo that process, but switch the major and the minor annuli.  See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz3QWrfPQj4